# MVC 4 ComplexType properties are not scaffolded

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scaffolding, complextype

I have a an address complex type as one of the properties of a user. When I scaffold out the domain model, the complex type is skipped in the view. Is there a fix for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post the ViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that MVC 4 is not capable of scaffolding out complex types yet. We will have to add the fileds in the form manually.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to scaffold complex types using the Package Manager console.